# Asp.Net Identity TwoFactorRememberBrowser cookie overwritten for second user

Tags: asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

Using Asp.Identity 2.2.1 and Two factor authentication, when a user logins, if the TwoFactorRememberBrowser cookie is not present they are brought to the SendCode action and they get a code sent to their email or phone. This is [standard sample code for MVC 5.2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-sms-and-email-two-factor-authentication). It they choose Remember Browser, then the cookie gets saved to allow them in the next time without needing a code.

Then a second user logins in on the same device. The are presented with the SendCode screen as above and cookie is saved for them.

However, if the first user comes back to login again, the TwoFactorRememberBrowser cookie has now be changed for the second user, and hence it no longer remembers the browser for this first user.

This does not make sense. As a user when I choose to remember the browser it should not depend on no one else subsequently remembering the same browser.

Is this the way Asp.Net Identity is designed to work, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is handed out by the server to the user agent (browser) and passed back whenever that user agent visits the same server, up until the cookie's expiry. This is cookie protocol.

Having 2 users share the same browser doesn't seem to be something the protocol manages.

Asp.Net Identity tries to ensure security by encrypting the cookie content, but misses the opportunity to discriminate on authenticated user when handing out the cookie, so must blindly accept the shared cookie when it is received.

I think it *is* the way Asp.Net Identity is designed to work. I think it's a design flaw.